# How can I get Mathematica to display PSI instead of lbf/in^2 as a unit?

Tags: units

I'm new to Mathematica and I've been trying to figure out if there was a way for Mathematica to display psi instead of its standard output, "lbf/in^2."

Comment: psi is ```lbf/in^2``` (pound-force by square inch).   ```lb``` (pound) is a unit of pound-mass. Mathematica reports pound-mass and pound-force as incompatible units.

Comment: You're right. It was a slight typo. Thanks!